# Will an InfoPath 2007 form with managed code work on SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, infopath, upgrade

I have an existing InfoPath 2007 form containing managed code. The form is now published on SharePoint 2007. The form will be edited and created using the InfoPath 2007 client, so no Web Form in this case.

I plan to migrate to SharePoint 2010. Since InfoPath 2007 is used as client and I do not want to bother the end user with upgrading, I still want to use InfoPath 2007 as client (No client upgrade to InfoPath 2010, yet)

Is it compatible ? Does it work without modifications? What should I change?

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft has published a white paper, *Business Productivity at Its Best* (which used to be called the Good-Better-Best white paper), in which they address specific SP 2010 functionality of various versions of Office: http://download.microsoft.com/DOWNLOAD/2/A/A/2AA0D302-86A6-4AA2-A0A4-4F15FA7DBF5C/BUSINESS%20PRODUCTIVITY%20AT%20ITS%20BEST_WHITEPAPER.PDF

Answer (score 2):

I would expect it to work, but you have some interesting variables there so it would be a good idea to plan for some validation before you commit to anything.

Normally there is some backwards compatibility with office apps.  InfoPath is a little different, but the underlying XML schema should be compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note, Visual Studio 2010 doesn't support InfoPath 2007 form projects (yet). So if you're planing on using that to write the managed code, you'll have issues.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the details of this on the server side. However InfoPath 2010 allows you to develop forms for either the 2007 client, 2007 Forms Server, 2010 client, or 2010 Forms Services. It also contains a Design Checker that verifies you aren't using features that won't be compatible in your target version.

From what I've seen nothing much has changed in Forms Services 2010. Like the rest of SharePoint 2010, it's more evolution rather than revolution. I would expect existing forms to work correctly (but as mentioned I haven't tested this).